# how to In sharepoint format view show only hours and minutes for a column

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a custom Format view for a list that I want to format a column called Date (date and time) so it's displays current date and time **without** seconds.

```
{
            "elmType": "div",
            "inlineEditField": "[$Date]",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-row-listPadding"
            },
            "style": {
              "margin-bottom": "10px",
              "margin-left": "10px",
              "font-size": "larger"
            },
            "txtContent": "=if(toLocaleDateString([$Date]) == '', toLocaleDateString([$Created]), toLocaleDateString([$Date])+' '+toLocaleTimeString([$Date]))"
          },
```

I've tried adding parameter to toLocalTime but doesn't seem to be supported because it will type out the code instead of showing the formatted date.

```
toLocaleTimeString([$Date], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'})
```

I also tried slice, substr, replace but doesn't seem to be supported as well.

Is this possible in sharepoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create a calculated column for displaying date/time in your preferred format?

If yes, create a calculated column with this formula
`=TEXT(Date,"dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm")`

Comment: Thanks, had some issues because of regional settings but I got it working now with a calculated column :)

Answer (score 0):

If your date column is of type "Date and Time" (including time), use JSON `txtContent` like:

```
"txtContent": "=if ([$Date.displayValue] == '', '–', [$Date.displayValue])"
```

Where `Date` is internal name of your list column. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

---

You can find other ways to check if date & time column is empty or not at: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)